# Unable to connect VMware VM to NAT network

Tags: networking, ubuntu, virtual-machine, vmware, nat

As a newer VMware Workstation user, I have a Windows 10 host, and I'm trying to setup Ubuntu 19.10 through NAT.

Many of the guides I'm seeing tell me to open and use the "Virtual Network Editor" but I don't see it, I think it's because it no longer exists and has been depreciated. Please tell me if I'm missing something.

In my VM settings everything looks good:

[image: VMware settings]

But the VM says it's not connected to the internet, and trying to install something through the terminal does not work, nor does browsing the snap store or going anywhere with firefox, just like you'd expect without internet.

[image]

Am I just looking at outdated sources for information? Have I set something up wrong? It's imperative I have this up for my boss by the end of the week.

Comment: Often in VMware to get it working I had to toggle to Bridged and then back to NAT.

Comment: @harrymc I have just tried that am have found in improvement, while I was on bridge though Ubuntu saw itself as plugged in but unable to connect even with a bridge.

Comment: Did you Install VMware Tools?

Comment: @harrymc I've been looking for a way to install them but I can't find it, where would I normally go to install it?

Comment: In VMware Workstation this is found in menu *VM > Install VMware Tools...* when the Windows VM is booted.

Comment: @harrymc I don't see a VM option in the nav bar https://imgur.com/a/uDbXgTE

Comment: You are using the limited Player, not the full VMware Workstation. If you don't have access to Workstation, you might get further with VirtualBox.

Comment: @harrymc Is there an option to get the full VMware Workstation free of charge?

Comment: No, VMware Workstation is trialware. In the past I have once used the trial version to configure one VM and I reverted to the Player once everything worked correctly. It worked for me in that case, but this solution is one-shot. Try VirtualBox, it is very similar.

Comment: @harrymc Ok, I can go back to Virtualbox, I've just had serious performance issues with it that I haven't had with Vmware Player.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have updated VMware Workstation to V15.5.1 (latest) and then look in the VMware program folder, run the Network Editor as Administrator, reset the VMware Network, restart the computer and try your guest NAT again.  Works here for Ubuntu and Kali both.

Comment: Under C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Player I see no Network Editor .exe or anything else under that name.

Comment: Using Windows 10, left click on the start button, scroll down to the VMware Folder, expand it, and Network Editor should be there.  If not, make sure your VMware version is current, and either (a) upgrade it and/or (b) do a VMware Workstation Repair from Programs and Features. That will bring back the editor

Comment: I have just tried and upgrade and a repair. There is still no network editor tool. https://imgur.com/KagsIoD

Comment: It is found in VMware Workstation menu *Edit > Virtual Network Editor...*

Comment: Assuming Windows 10 is current, you need Workstation V15.5.1 .   Uninstall it, restart and install it again. It works perfectly here

Comment: For VmWare Workstation 17 it's called vmnetcfg.exe